# Extract numbers from "dd.dd AAA dd.dd BBB" or "AAA dd.dd BBB dd.dd"

Tags: python, regex, pandas, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to extract two values from arbitrary text, formatted in variable ways. The two values are different, and I want to distinguish them based on a nearby sring, lets say "DDT" and "EEG". Here are some examples of how the strings can be formatted.

```
This contains 42.121% DDT and 2.1% EEG

Now with DDT: 12% EEG: 23.2%

47 DDT 22 EEG

EEG N/A DDT 43

5% EEG 20% DDT and more
```

Essentially I need to be able to select both values preceded by and followed by their identifier.

I have been using a | between two selectors to capture both "cases" for each value, but I am having trouble. I want to prevent the regex from selecting "12% EEG" in the second example line. I am trying to use negative lookaheads and positive lookbehinds but can't make it work.

Here is the regex for selecting just ddt

```
(?<=eeg)(\d{1,3}\.?\d{1,6}).{,10}?ddt|ddt(?!.*eeg).{,10}?(\d{1,3}\.?\d{1,6})
```

This is the closest I have gotten, but it still does not work correctly. This version fails to match "20% DDT."

My original regex did not use lookbehinds, but also fails in some cases.

```
(?:(?:(\d{1,3}\.?\d*)[^(?:eeg)]{0,10}?ddt)|(?:ddt[^(?:eeg)]{0,10}?(\d{1,3}\.?\d*)))
```

My original approach fails to recognize the 23.2% EEG strings formatted like this. "DDT: 12% EEG: 23.2%"

I am not sure if this type of selector is possible with regex, but I want to use regex in order to vectorize this extraction. I have a function that does a good job of characterizing these strings, but it is very slow on large datasets (~1 million records). The regex runs quickly and is easy to apply to vectors, which is why I want to use it. If there are other suggestions to solve this problem with NLP or numpy/pandas functions I am open to those as well.

Comment: How many cases are there (can you enumerate them all)?

Comment: I guess there are really 4 cases. "EEG dd.dd DDT dd.dd", "dd.dd EEG dd.dd DDT". "DDT dd.dd EEG dd.dd", "dd.dd DDT dd.dd EEG." The problem with creating an individual regex for each is I still need to distinguish each case. I don't know if that could be done more efficiently than my naive value extraction function.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following, at least for these cases:

1/ work out which is first EEG or DDT:

```
In [11]: s.str.extract("(DDT|EEG)")
Out[11]:
     0
0  DDT
1  DDT
2  DDT
3  EEG
4  EEG
```

2/ pull out all the numbers:

```
In [12]: s.str.extract("(\d+\.?\d*|N/A).*?(\d+\.?\d*|N/A)")
Out[12]:
        0     1
0  42.121   2.1
1      12  23.2
2      47    22
3     N/A    43
4       5    20
```

To get rid of the N/A you can apply to_numeric:

```
In [13]: res = s.str.extract("(\d+\.?\d*|N/A).*?(\d+\.?\d*|N/A)").apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', axis=1)

In [14]: res
Out[14]:
        0     1
0  42.121   2.1
1  12.000  23.2
2  47.000  22.0
3     NaN  43.0
4   5.000  20.0
```

Now you have to rearrange these columns to match their respective DDT/EEG:

```
In [15]: pd.DataFrame({
           "DDT": res[0].where(s.str.extract("(DDT|EEG)")[0] == 'DDT', res[1]),
           "EEG": res[1].where(s.str.extract("(DDT|EEG)")[0] == 'DDT', res[0])
         })
Out[15]:
      DDT   EEG
0  42.121   2.1
1  12.000  23.2
2  47.000  22.0
3  43.000   NaN
4  20.000   5.0
```

Here `s` is the original Series/column:

```
In [21]: s
Out[21]:
0    This contains 42.121% DDT and 2.1% EEG
1              Now with DDT: 12% EEG: 23.2%
2                             47 DDT 22 EEG
3                            EEG N/A DDT 43
4                   5% EEG 20% DDT and more
dtype: object
```

This assumes both DDT and EEG are both present, you might need to NaN out the rows where this isn't the case (which only have one of DDT/EEG)...